# Does react-native-touch-id support android?

Tags: android, react-native

I cant find anything saying one way or the other. Looking through everything, theres no reason that it shouldnt, however I am new to developing on either android or ios, so Im not entirely sure of the different methods available and how they link with react-native and react-native-touch-id

The only thing I can find online is something from two years ago that states react-native-touch-id does not support android "yet". And I found another node package called react-native-touch-id-android which I am having trouble building

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use React Native Touch ID for both iOS and Android on the latest version of RN. Someone forked this repo to also allow the device passcode as a fallback.

https://github.com/tradle/react-native-local-auth